# Mutating an object state by directly replacing it's value with an object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Laravel project using vue & vuex. While everything is working fine, I find that in mutations I have to loop through the array then push it to the state.  replacing the state directly with the new array doesn't seem to work.

So, in my mutations, this does not work:

```
mutations: {
    setProducts(state, products) {
        state.products = products
    }
}
```

But, this one does:

```
mutations: {
    setProducts(state, products) {
        products.forEach(product => {
            state.products.push(product)
        }
    }
}
```

It's not really a problem because it works, but am just wondering why the first one doesn't work when that seems to be more efficient.

Comment: i think the first one should work while second one doesnt work?

Comment: They should both work

Comment: Try returning the value: `setProducts(state, products) { return state.products = products }`

Comment: Or: `setProducts: (state, products) => state.products = products`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights the return value from mutations is not used and the arrow syntax is functionally identical so it's not going to make a difference

Comment: @Phil When I set mutations I use the arrow syntax and it works just fine. Not sure what the issue is otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also trigger view updates. The wrapped methods are:

```
push()
pop()
shift()
unshift()
splice()
sort()
reverse()
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods